# How do I center my nav bar on its own line?

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sm6yvwmu/1/

I'm trying to center my nav bar; however, my aside element keeps coming up in the same line as my nav bar. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
}

#nav li {
  float: left;
}

#nav a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>Portfolio</header>

<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Multimedia</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<aside>
  Michelle
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated Fidle](https://jsfiddle.net/sm6yvwmu/2/)

```
#nav li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Use "inline-block" instead "float"

Answer (score 1):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#bed33b10b7298bfb9ba85eaf5ccb7ed3

You have `display block` applied to `aside` so it'll automatically be displayed in a new line, unless you have float. So remove float and you're good.

You could also tell each list to be displayed [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) or [inline-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

aside {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>Portfolio</header>

<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Multimedia</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<aside>
  Michelle
</aside>
```